# Does anyone know how to create an Angular 8 DatePicker using Bootstrap without using ngBootstrap?

Tags: angular

I tried using this, but it won't bind to my [(ngModel)] usage.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

This looks promising, but it hasn't been updated in years.

https://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Since you are open to using external libraries, why not [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Good question! This statement from the ng-Bootstrap documentation concerns me. "No, the goal of ng-bootstrap is to completely replace JavaScript implementation for components. Nor should you include other dependencies like jQuery or popper.js. It is not necessary and might interfere with ng-bootstrap code." I've already found instances where I've had to use jQuery and JavaScript to implement specific features in a version 8 Angular application. I would rather not rely on a framework that does not work well with them. Perhaps I'm reading too much into this, but this does concern me.

Comment: [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) is coded for Angular and does not need jQuery. I have never had problems with ng-bootstrap when jQuery is included in my Angular projects. As long as you don't install Bootstrap Javascript code, it should work well.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I'm using both bootstrap.min.js and popper.min.js in my project. Are you saying that all I have to do is comment out bootstrap.min.js in my index.html and install ng-Bootstrap? Once I do that, it should work with all of my existing code??? Thanks!

Comment: You would also have to replace the Bootstrap components with the equivalent `ng-bootstrap` components and directives.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Ok, I went ahead and installed ng-Bootstrap and now none of my Modals are working. Anyway, thanks for your help. I will work on refactoring all my Modals to work with ng-Bootstrap.